# Python 2 : Cannot understand why this evaluates to a String instead of the List Value

Tags: python-2.7

Beginner Dictionary question here.  I have this code:

```
import random

abilities = {
'Spell': '''fireball missile dread curse fear teleport shield 
cure heal blast reveal fade taunt reveal haste shock'''.split(),
'Weapon': '''axe sword mace club longbow shortbow crossbow greatsword 
greataxe dagger shortsword longsword staff claw'''.split(),
'Skill': '''jump slash parry dodge block smash grab jab evade stab 
crush charm lure lift throw grapple punch'''.split(),
'Monster': '''goblin troll ogre ninja pirate knight warlock witch 
mage lich ooze gargoyle bandit thief wizard swordmaster'''.split()}

def getAbility(abilityDict):
    #get ability key
    abilityKey = random.choice(list(abilityDict.keys()))
    #get random value from ability key
    abilityValue = random.randint(0, len(abilityDict[abilityKey]) -1)
    return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey]

ability, abilityKey = getAbility(abilities)

print abilityKey, ability
```

Which when I call the print function will evaluate to a String like "Monster ooze" or "Weapon sword"

However, when I change this line in the function:

```
return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey]
```

to this:

```
return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue]]
```

and change this:

```
ability, abilityKey = getAbility(abilities)
print abilityKey, ability
```

to this:

```
ability = getAbility(abilities)
print ability
```

Then the print function evaluates to a random value from a random key in list format, so ['bandit'] or ['axe']

My question is this: 
Why does return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey] return a string and return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue]] return a list?

I just need to know why, because simply memorizing it won't really help me grasp the concept of python dictionaries.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey] return a string and return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue]] return a list?

It doesn't.  They both return lists.  In the first case, you're returning a list containing two strings:

```
>>> getAbility(abilities)
['slash', 'Skill']
```

And you unpack this list into two elements:

```
>>> ability, abilityKey = getAbility(abilities)
>>> ability
'heal'
>>> abilityKey
'Spell'
```

which you then print:

```
>>> print(abilityKey, ability)
Spell heal
```

Typically you'd use a tuple for this, not a list (i.e. drop the outer `[]`), but both work here.

In your second case, `return [abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue]]`, you return a list containing one string.  (Which is a little weird-- usually you'd simply return the string itself):

```
>>> getAbility2(abilities)
['teleport']
```

As near as I can tell, your confusion doesn't have to do with dictionaries at all, but the fact you're comparing two different things, namely `print some_string, some_other_string` with `print some_list_with_one_string`.

(PS: since you already know about `random.choice`, then you can use `random.choice(abilityDict[abilityKey])` rather than go via the index with `random.randint(0, len(abilityDict[abilityKey]) -1)`.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand.  When I removed the brackets outside the return and converted it to a tuple like you said, then return abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue] returned a random value from the Dictionary as a String.  Visually, it makes a lot more sense that way, however I still am a bit confused as to why the first case is returning a list containing two strings.  I will come back to this and fool around with it some more until I truly understand what is going on. :D

Comment: Because you told it to!  `[abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey] ` has two brackets around it, which specify a list.  `[1,2]` is a list of two integers; `['c', (2.3,4.5)]` is a list with a string as the first element and a tuple of two floats as the second;  `[abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue], abilityKey] ` is a list with `abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue]` (a string) as the first element and `abillityKey` (which is a string) as the second.

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it now.  That actually helps a lot.  When I take away the ,abilityKey I am basically telling the function to return a list because I surround the String abilityDict[abilityKey][abilityValue] inside a [].  It all makes sense now I was just looking at it the wrong way.  Thank you again!